# Is there any way to get namespaces based on a particular metadata label

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

My namespace has some custom metadata labels. Some have the labels some don't. Is there any way to get the namespaces which has a particular label using kubectl?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Like so:

```
$ kubectl create ns nswithlabels

$ kubectl label namespace nswithlabels this=thing

$ kubectl describe ns/nswithlabels
Name:         nswithlabels
Labels:       this=thing
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Active

No resource quota.

No resource limits.

$ kubectl get ns -l=this
NAME           STATUS    AGE
nswithlabels   Active    6m
```

Note: I could have also used `-l=this=thing` in the last command to specify both key and value required to match.